# C++ Function to add nums in a vector, with push back function

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to create a function which add a number in a list, I simply use the push_back function. My function has parameters a vector of integer and the number which is supposed to be added. But nothing happens, any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
    
using namespace std;
    
void print_vec(vector <int> vec);
int add_num(vector <int> vec, int num);
    
void print_vec(vector <int> vec){ //Print out the input list
    cout<<"["; 
    if (vec.size() == 0)
        cout<<"] The list is empty"<<endl;
        
    else if  (vec.size() > 0){
        for (size_t i{0}; i<vec.size(); ++i){
            if (i == vec.size()-1)
                cout<<vec[i];
            else
                cout<<vec[i]<<", ";
        }
        cout<<"]"<<endl;
    } 
}
```

Here is my function. If I only type in my main function, the push back function, it works.

```
int add_num(vector <int> vec, int num){
    vec.push_back(num);
}
    
int main()
{
    vector <int> input_vec = {};
        
    print_vec(input_vec);
    int user_input {0};
        
    cout<<"Enter an integer"<<endl;
    cin>>user_input;
        
    add_num(input_vec, user_input);
    print_vec(input_vec);    
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the concepts of "passing by value" and "passing by reference". Right now, you're passing the input vector by value, meaning that the function only makes changes to a local copy of that vector and leaving the original untouched.

Comment: `int add_num(vector <int> vec, int num){` -> `int add_num(vector <int> &vec, int num){` either typo or you need to learn about pass by value/reference.

Answer (score 1):

You are only modifying a function-local copy of your vector

```
int add_num(vector<int> vec, int num){
    vec.push_back(num);   
}
```

Instead you should pass a mutable reference to your vector

```
int add_num(vector<int>& vec, int num){
    vec.push_back(num);   
}
```

Comment: There must be hundreds of duplicates of this.

Comment: I change it and the compiler get this error:
 56:34: error: call of overloaded 'add_num(std::vector<int>&, int&)' is ambiguous

Comment: @alexspi did you also change the function declaration?

Comment: No, now works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in `vector <int> vec` by value. Therefore, any changes made to `vec` inside the function are made to local variable only. If you want to change the passed in vector, you should pass by reference like so:

```
int add_num(vector <int> &vec, int num){

    vec.push_back(num);
    
}
```